# How to programmatically load and stream Kafka topic to a PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

There are many way to read/ write spark dataframe to kafka. Am trying to read messages from kafka topic and create a data frame out of it. Am able to get pull the messages from topic, but am unable to convert it to a datafame. Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

consumer = KafkaConsumer('Jim_Topic')

for message in consumer:
    data = message
    print(data) # Printing the messages properly
    df = data.map # am unable to convert it to a dataframe.
```

I tried below way as well,

```
df = spark \
  .read \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "Jim_Topic") \
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

Getting below error,

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use-case, you can

1. Either [create a Kafka source for streaming queries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-streaming-queries)
2. or [create a Kafka source of batch queries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries)

---

**For Streaming Queries**

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "Jim_Topic")
  .load()

# Query data
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
  .as[(String, String)]
```

---

**For Batch Queries**

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "Jim_Topic")
  .load()

# Query data
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
  .as[(String, String)]
```

---

Make sure to add the required dependencies as well:

```
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.0.2
```

(replace with your Spark's version - the above refers to Spark version `2.0.2`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I tired this logic already, am getting below error `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;`

Comment: @JimMacaulay How are you running your app? Is it through `spark-submit`?

Comment: am running from PyCharm directly. Not with `spark-submit`

Comment: @JimMacaulay You need to add the required dependency. See my updated answer.

Comment: Could you please help me to add the dependency. Am not sure how to add it. If Java i would have added in maven dependency. Am not sure about Python

Comment: @JimMacaulay https://bytes.grubhub.com/managing-dependencies-and-artifacts-in-pyspark-7641aa89ddb7

Comment: Still am stuck with this. Is there a possibility to add the dependency in the code itself? Rather that configurations. Or can we configure in PyCharm IDE

Comment: Tried adding dependency. Still am getting below error `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.load.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated` Would you be able to help me

Comment: try adding you dependency in the build.sbt file